# Is there version control software with commit messages that preserves macOS tags?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, finder-tag, versions, extended-attributes

As I mentioned in my answer on [tags best practices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269194/220376), the [distributed version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) software (VCS) [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) does not preserve macOS [tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(metadata)) (or other [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)). Is there version control software (distributed or centralized) that features *commit messages* (like Git) *and* that preserves macOS tags? (The [built-in versioning system in macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202255) does not include commit messages.) I am especially interested in software that can be easily installed through one of the [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for macOS, but any software that meets the criteria is welcome.